# BigQuery date partition condition from subquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a date partitioned table, however costs and speed does not improve when the date condition is fetched from a subquery. The subquery fetches a single value of type DATE, however it is not used to run a partitioned query, instead the whole table is fetched. If I enter the date as a string, it works perfectly, just not from the subquery.

```
(
            SELECT
              *
            FROM
              `mydataset.mydataset.mytable`
            WHERE
              `datetime` > (
              SELECT
                DISTINCT updated_at_datetime
              FROM
                `mydataset.mydataset.my_other_table`
              LIMIT
                1)
              AND `date` >= DATE(DATETIME_TRUNC((
                  SELECT
                    DISTINCT updated_at_datetime
                  FROM
                    `mydataset.mydataset.my_other_table`
                  LIMIT
                    1), DAY)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-partitioned-tables#best_practices_for_partition_pruning):

> To limit the partitions that are scanned in a query, use a constant expression in your filter. **If you use dynamic expressions in your query filter, BigQuery must scan all of the partitions**.

If you can run your query as a script, an approach is split in two statements:

```sql
DECLARE LAST_PARTITION DEFAULT (SELECT MAX(updated_at_datetime) FROM `mydataset.mydataset.my_other_table`);

(
            SELECT
              *
            FROM
              `mydataset.mydataset.mytable`
            WHERE
              `datetime` > LAST_PARTITION
              AND `date` >= DATE(DATETIME_TRUNC(LAST_PARTITION));
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work. I think it's because the value still depends on the query. Can you think of any other way?

Comment: @evam What you mean with `the value still depends on the query`? Are you running a query different from the sample in the question? What is the partition column for `mytable`? In the answer, if you table was partitioned by column `datetime` the query will only scan the expected partitions. Remember to put the partition filter first in the `WHERE`.

Comment: The query is identical. The table is partitioned by the date column, a partition by datetime is not possible. Yes, I did put the date as the first condition. Declaring a variable doesn't make the value a constant, it just makes it easier to re-use in the query to avoid repetition and a long query string. The value is still considered dynamic because it is fetched as part of the query. To take advantage of partitioning BQ needs to know what the value is BEFORE starting, so it can make an execution plan. Once it starts, it's too late and all partitions are scanned.

Comment: @evam When running as SCRIPT, each statement will run in a separated job. So the DECLARE will run first, then pass a parameter to the query. When used correctly, this will avoid a full scan. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Njb17.png